# How to set references of objects in a typesafe way in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to wire up objects in a typesafe way, with typesafe autocompletion.

Example:

```
type Animal = {
    owner1: Person,
    owner2: Person,
    numberOfLegs: number
}

type Person = {
    animal1: Animal,
    animal2: Animal,
    name: string
}

let animal : Animal = ...
let person : Person = ...
```

When I am writing a line like this:

```
// wire(object1, object2, field1, field2) does
//   object1.field1 = object2
//   object2.field2 = object1
wire(animal, person,...
```

I want the IDE to help me autocomplete: but the 3rd parameter SHALL BE RESTRICTED to "owner1" or "owner2" and NOT "numberOfLegs", because at that point it is clear for the typescript complier, that person has type Person and in Animal type it is only 'owner1' and 'owner2' fields which have that type, 'numberOfLegs' does have a different type.

Something like this, but unfortunately this does not work:

```
function wire<
  T1,
  T2,
  F1 extends keyof T1,
  F2 extends keyof T2,
  S1 extends F1 & (T1[F1] extends T2 ? F1 : never),
  S2 extends F2 & (T2[F2] extends T1 ? F2 : never),
>(
  o1: T1,
  o2: T2,
  f1: S1,
  f2: S2,
)
{
  o1[f1] = o2
  o2[f2] = o1
  return
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to worry about type checking inside the *implementation* of `wire()`, since I think your main concern here is the behavior from the *caller's* side.  The implementation will probably need some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to suppress errors, since the compiler can't easily understand the sort of type logic you're doing here.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) for a feature request which would make the implementation type check.

Okay, so here's one approach to the call signature for `wire()`:

```
declare function wire<T1, T2>(
    o1: T1, o2: T2, 
    k1: KeysMatchingForWrites<T1, T2>, 
    k2: KeysMatchingForWrites<T2, T1>
): void;

type KeysMatchingForWrites<T, V> =
    keyof { [K in keyof T as [V] extends [T[K]] ? K : never]: any };
```

The `KeysMatchingForWrites<T, V>` type takes a type `T` and returns the names of the properties of `T` to which you could safely write a value of type `V`.  It is implemented via [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), where we keep only the keys where `V` is a subtype of the property type `T[K]` (the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `[V] extends [T[K]] ? K : never` produces such keys; I decided to wrap `V` and `T[K]` with `[`...`]` in order to make it not [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)).

Let's see if it works:

```
wire(animal, person, "owner1", "animal1");
// function wire<Animal, Person>(
//   o1: Animal, o: Person, k1: "owner1" | "owner2", k2: "animal1" | "animal2"
// ): void
```

Looks good.  The type of `k1` is `"owner1" | "owner2"`, and `k2` is `"animal1" | "animal2"` as desired.  Neither `numberOfLegs` nor `name` are acceptable.

By the way, the reason why `KeysMatchingForWrites<T, V>` checks that `V` is a subtype of `T[K]` and not vice versa is because you are writing, and you want to make sure that it is safe to write as opposed to read.  For example:

```
interface SuperFoo { u: string; }
interface Foo extends SuperFoo { v: Bar }
interface SubFoo extends Foo { w: string; }
declare const foo: Foo;

interface Bar {
    x: SuperFoo, // wider is fine
    y: Foo,
    z: SubFoo; // narrower is not
}
declare const bar: Bar;

// function wire<Foo, Bar>(o1: Foo, o2: Bar, k1: "v", k2: "x" | "y"): void
wire(foo, bar, "v", "x"); // okay, you can assign a Foo to a SuperFoo
wire(foo, bar, "v", "y"); // okay, you can assign a Foo to a Foo
wire(foo, bar, "v", "z"); // error, you cannot necessarily assign a Foo to a SubFoo
```

In the above, you are writing `foo.v` to the `k2` property of `bar`.  Since `foo.v` is of type `Foo`, then you can only safely assign to `bar.x` and `bar.y`.  Since `bar.y` is a `SuperFoo` and every `Foo` is a `SuperFoo`, that's fine.  But you can't assign to `bar.z` because that needs to be a `SubFoo`, and not every `Foo` is a `SubFoo`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAxAewCcB1U7YCBAHgBUAaKANQD4oBeAKCn6gBreMQBmUAN5QA2jCh4hI8QygoE01gF0oEAB41cAEwQyGszdoD8sKAC4ouCADcIpTfZS4QUAL4BuHh5DCHQAGxRSaFEAV1x0YGxiXCgAd2xIxgBGFgYAJnYACj4BYkz7BmyoYlzy3JZBMth4ZDQsPCIySmpaLJz8+pqmxFQMHAISCioaejyczPYeAEp7J2JsQwCeUEgoAEFcbABbFFDuSWL+YhTHUkaABVcEJICBKuvXQYfSJ9wXgVxoocAEauADyogAMhB8Ah7ADga4Av5AttoF8fmcJBdVAdjqFGvsjic-vxPETQoNCXiSQ4UIcIPYEMAqAQkZsgiFwpEoOgkkyceT7FTiRywhFoLzcPzIN8kvZ0c8eGlIgUyXiWDKfiwAERXG6ZbU6tUnA2LAIAenNUBicQSSVS6QgdGFoRYCtwhR4lpKBNxJxYxHljyS9Uauvet21UAAPlBwzdcoahINtcb8VHY6m-RTtV6rcsoKt1oEeHgaKRRCh0NAAMrRGUkYjnV7RRnM9pI0u4cuV6tQRs6fQQIwmOsN4hNrGvJz2ABCER4Pi7ParteiQIHegMxn7E+bAhSbZZ+E7wTF3Ml-NEE-sjc2Zdcveg89I+-4unsY9cjZY3rSwVfbATFEPAIGxEBbwnJhsQAL0-dc7ygb1cAiUgrlceQTFwYhgEXUUuQlPlgCgIEIjnCJNm9G14kSZJlSdH8oBfQpSkg4gA0GF9Q3sbUnCTQQU10DM4xAbUCyLQwlUdApr3YkiIh1PidSEs0kKtYhBBQEAWBAYhoh5TxVAQBBsHwZIUF3JtgCbCyv1IRspJVWSWFI0hFKTbVRNU70NK0nS9IM8zjNM8zLKgazVEsxyIBkqD5LcuMlLjGCxL8NSdFINCEt0-T0E8bDiMcatjIibBQm8NQTLMyKBwi2yEInEsgA)

Comment: GOSH! You are awesome! Thank you very much, it truly works! Did not even know about key remapping and the "[...]" "distributive trick". Can you please comment if any of these are theoretically necessary with current features of ts-compiler to get the expected behaviour? I am not an expert but this "key remapping" seems to be something otherwise impossible(?). Also, I do not want to waste your time, but can you please comment why my solution was not right? With "S1 extends F1 & (T1[F1] extends T2 ? F1 : never)" I wanted to "filter" F1, but it run onto never & errored out instead filtering, why?

Comment: There are no inference sites for `F1` or `F2` in your version; they are only mentioned inside constraints for other type parameters, and constraints don't serve as inference sites (see [ms/TS#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234)). So inference fails.  There are probably other issues but that's the first thing stopping it from working.